# Относительные ссылки от каталога, а не сайта или документа

Tags: html, href

Допустимо ли прописывать в атрибуте `href` тега `base` URL каталога (например http://domain.com/path/), а не конечного документа? Дело в том, что так очень удобно формировать относительные ссылки на изображения, скрипты и т.п.

Проблема следующая. Я разрабатываю CMS на PHP. С помощью `mod_rewrite` все запросы вида `http://domain.com/path/artist/edit/25` приводятся к виду `http://domain.com/path/index.php?url=/artist/edit/25`. Таким образом, часть URL после `http://domain.com/path/` является виртуальной.

Для удобства и повышения производительности CMS, верстая HTML я использую ссылки в формате `<a href="artist/show">...</a>` и ссылки на ресурсы (изображения, скрипты и пр.) в формате `<link href="ui/css/style.css"...>`.

Всё это работает с использованием HTML-конструкции, которая одинакова для любого URL конечного материала:

```
    ...
    <base href="http://domain.com/path/" />
    ...
```

CSS и скрипты адресуются так:

```
    ...
    <!-- Custom page style CSS -->
    <link href="ui/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
    <!-- Support for CSS3 media query in IE8 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ui/js/respond.js"></script>
    <!-- MooTools 1.6.0 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ui/js/MooTools-Core-1.6.0.js"></script>
    ...
```

Пытаясь глубже разобраться в теме я нашел несколько статей и сайт https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base где указывается, что `<base href=...>` должен содержать URL текущего документа. Если это действительно так, то рушится вся первоначальная задумка.

Посмотрев HTML-код популярных и средне-популярных сайтов, удалось выяснить, что около половины предпочитают вообще не использовать относительные ссылки, 10%-15% делают так же, как я, остальные используют относительную адресацию от доменного имени (используют ссылки вида `/css/style.css`).

Отсюда ряд связанных вопросов:

1. Насколько распространенной является практика, когда `<base href=...>` указывает на директорию, а не конечный документ?
2. Соответствует ли такая практика утвержденному стандарту?
3. Если `<base href=...>` не указывает на URL конечного документа, возможны ли какие-либо проблемы с индексацией сайта поисковыми роботами?

Также, в комментариях, хотелось бы услышать мнения относительно способов упрощения формата ссылок на ресурсы.